# Ng-pickadate translations

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

Are you used [ng-pickadate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-pickadate) - angular directive for pickadate.js  and whether it has translation like pure library and how to use it ? Or do you know any other solutions with this functionality for angularjs ?